# Core Plot not showing scatter plot line

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to get a simple scatter plot showing with Core Plot, but for whatever reason no line is showing. My delegate methods *are* being called (`numberOfRecordsForPlot:` and `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`). Here's what I'm doing to set up the graph:

```
CPTGraphHostingView* extendedHost = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, extendedView.frameBottom, self.view.frameWidth, roomForScrollingComponentAndGraph - extendedForecastView.frameHeight)];
[extendedHost setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor(1.f)];
[self.view addSubview:extendedHost];

CPTXYGraph* extendedGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:extendedHost.bounds];
extendedGraph.paddingBottom = graphPadding;
extendedGraph.paddingLeft = graphPadding;
extendedGraph.paddingRight = graphPadding;
extendedGraph.paddingTop = graphPadding;

CPTXYPlotSpace* extendedPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)extendedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
extendedPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(20)];
extendedPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(100)];

[extendedGraph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];

CPTXYAxisSet* extendedAxisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet*)extendedGraph.axisSet;

CPTXYAxis* extendedX = extendedAxisSet.xAxis;
extendedX.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
extendedX.titleTextStyle = style;
extendedX.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);

NSMutableArray* extendedMajorTicks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int idx = 0; idx < 14; idx++) {
    [extendedMajorTicks addObject:@(idx)];
}
extendedX.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:extendedMajorTicks];
extendedX.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided;
extendedX.delegate = self;

CPTXYAxis* extendedY = extendedAxisSet.yAxis;
extendedY.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4;
extendedY.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
extendedY.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
extendedY.titleTextStyle = style;
extendedY.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
extendedY.delegate = self;

CPTScatterPlot* extendedPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
extendedPlot.delegate = self;

CPTMutableLineStyle *extendedLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
extendedLineStyle.lineJoin = kCGLineJoinRound;
extendedLineStyle.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
extendedLineStyle.miterLimit = 2.f;
extendedLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.f;
extendedLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

extendedPlot.dataLineStyle = extendedLineStyle;
extendedPlot.dataSource = self;
extendedPlot.title = @"Extended";
_extendedPlot = extendedPlot;

[extendedGraph addPlot:extendedPlot];

_extendedGraph = extendedGraph;

[extendedHost setHostedGraph:_extendedGraph];
```

I feel like it's something small that I'm missing as I have used Core Plot in other projects before and I have compared my code and I don't think I'm missing anything vital, but alas, I seem to be.

Comment: Do the plot space ranges enclose your plot data? The default ranges are [0, 1] for both x and y.

Comment: I was not doing so before, but after adding the plot space ranges (I edited my code above; the ranges are set after the plot is created near the bottom), I see no change. The data varies but I know that it will fall inside the ranges I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot's plot space (`extendedPlotSpace`) is `nil` until the plot is added to a graph. Either move your plot space setup to after the plot is part of the graph, or use `graph.defaultPlotSpace` instead.

Comment: Well, setting the plot's plot space properly fixed my tick location issue; the ticks were being set properly but the plot's region just wasn't focused on a wide enough area to see them. My plot still isn't being shown, though. I've posted my new code that shows the ticks.

Comment: What is `lineStyle`? If it is `nil`, the plot won't draw a data line.

Comment: `lineStyle` was the CPTMutableLineStyle that I was sharing between two plots, so its definition wasn't actually in my code snippet. I've changed my code to use separate line styles for both plots, as you can see now. `NSLog`-ing the line style shows that it is non-nil.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I tried using dummy data for my graph instead of the data from our web service. The problems I've been experiencing are because at first our data is `nil`, so all of the y-values are 0. When the data is loaded I'm calling `reloadData` on the plot, but the data isn't reloaded.

Comment: Are you calling `-reloadData` from the main thread? Are your datasource methods called again?

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Wrapping my call to `reloadData` in a `dispatch_async()` call fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your help, Eric!